# Tensorflow path of file isn't valid

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, filepath, tensorflow.js

so I'm trying to set up a very basic tfjs project but am stuck in an early part of getting it running. Running into a file path not found error: 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory'. My code looks like this:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs')
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

async function test_function() {
    const house_sales_dataset = tf.data.csv('file://./datasets/kc_house_data.csv');
    const sample = house_sales_dataset.take(10);
    try {
        const dataArray = await sample.toArray();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

test_function();
```

My file structure for the npm project is the following:

Root project directory is called 'tensorflow-practice'. Inside this is app.js, package.json, package-lock.json, node-modules, and a folder called 'datasets'. Inside 'datasets' folder is the .csv file called 'kc_house_data.csv'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRCw0.jpg

Not sure why this isn't working...any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your project visually please instead of writing it out? I think that would help someone answer the question.

Comment: @Joe Added to the question.

Comment: Your path is wrong, try this `tf.data.csv(require('path').join(__dirname, 'datasets/kc_house_data.csv'))`. The `file` protocol has 3 forward slashes like `file:///`

Comment: @darklightcode It says 'Only absolute URLs are supported'. It says this after defining house_sales_dataset as 'tf.data.csv(require('path').join(__dirname, 'datasets/kc_house_data.csv'))'

Comment: not directly related, but importing both @tensorflow/tfjs and @tensorflow/tfjs-node is a mistake. drop @tensorflow/tfjs and do `const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')`